# citet and citep behaves like cite

Tags: citing, natbib

I am new with LaTeX so please bare with me. If its matter editor that I am using is TeXMaker, the TeXLive is installed. Why `\citep` and `\citet` did not display citation as a "Goossens et al. (1993)" or "(Goossens et al., 1993)" but just as a simple number in brackets `[1]` (exactly same like `\cite`)?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


% old citation style (used by \cite)
%\usepackage{cite}

% package used by \citep and \citet
\usepackage[sort&compress,square,comma,authoryear]{natbib}

% makes color citations
\usepackage[dvips,dvipdfm,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=red,linkcolor=red,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

% document begin
\begin{document}

% author and title
\title{My Article}
\author{Author Name}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Blablabla said by \cite{lamport94} cite example. Blablabla said by \cite[p.~215]{impj} cite example. Blablabla said by \cite{fo,norman,lamport94} multiple cite example. Blablabla said by \nocite{lamport94} nocite example.
Blablabla said by \citep{lamport94} citep example. Blablabla said by \citet*{impj} citet example. Blablabla said by \citet{impj} citet example.

% this must be set to use natbib (citep, citet)
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

% number 99 determines how much citation can be included in file (maximum 99)
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd Edition,
  1994.

   \bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\em Readings compiled for History
  21.479.}  1991.

  \bibitem{impj}  The Japan Reader {\em Imperial Japan 1800-1945} 1973:
  Random House, N.Y.

  \bibitem{norman} E. H. Norman {\em Japan's emergence as a modern
  state} 1940: International Secretariat, Institute of Pacific
  Relations.

  \bibitem{fo} Bob Tadashi Wakabayashi {\em Anti-Foreignism and Western
  Learning in Early-Modern Japan} 1986: Harvard University Press.

\end{thebibliography}



\end{document}
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management
```

Comment: No, I cannot see any errors in tex maker. Seems that I am using pdfTeXk i dont exactly know the log file is here [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Fx2zE3nR)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The author-year citation style requires usage of BibTeX or specially formatted `\bibitem` commands.

If you don't want to use BibTeX, then you must hand format your `thebibliography` environment as in the following example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


\usepackage[sort&compress,square,comma,authoryear]{natbib}

% makes color citations
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=red,linkcolor=red,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

% document begin
\begin{document}

% author and title
\title{My Article}
\author{Author Name}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Blablabla said by \cite{lamport94} cite example. Blablabla said by \cite[p.~215]{impj} cite example. Blablabla said by \cite{fo,norman,lamport94} multiple cite example. Blablabla said by \nocite{lamport94} nocite example.
Blablabla said by \citep{lamport94} citep example. Blablabla said by \citet*{impj} citet example. Blablabla said by \citet{impj} citet example.

% this must be set to use natbib (citep, citet) but requires BibTeX
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

% number 99 determines how much citation can be included in file (maximum 99)
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[Lamport(1994)]{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd Edition,
  1994.

\bibitem[Dower(1991)]{notes} John W. Dower {\em Readings compiled for History
  21.479.}  1991.

\bibitem[Japan Reader(1973)]{impj}  The Japan Reader {\em Imperial Japan 1800-1945} 1973:
  Random House, N.Y.

\bibitem[Norman(1940)]{norman} E. H. Norman {\em Japan's emergence as a modern
  state} 1940: International Secretariat, Institute of Pacific
  Relations.

\bibitem[Wakabayashi(1986]{fo} Bob Tadashi Wakabayashi {\em Anti-Foreignism and Western
  Learning in Early-Modern Japan} 1986: Harvard University Press.

\end{thebibliography}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Never pass explicit driver names to `hyperref`.

---

If you want a "mixed" system like "Author [number]", then you can say

```
\usepackage[sort&compress,square,comma,numbers]{natbib}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\citeext}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}~\cite{#1}}
```

and then `\citeext{lamport}` will give you

> Lamport [1]

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. I am also wondering if there is there possibility to add numbers under References section and cite like "said by Lamport [1]" ? Tried to use something like: \usepackage[sort&compress,square,comma,authoryear,numbers]{natbib} But did not worked. Thank you very much

Comment: @WakanTanka I'll add a way for you.

Comment: what did you mean by this, sorry for my english, id did not catch what you've tried to say. I see some options for `\bibliographystyle` and also the "number" options for natbib. Also maybe it would be possibe to cite two times one time for author name and second for number. Or by using BibTex. Dont know I am just begginer.

Comment: @WakanTanka I removed my previous comment because I understood only later what you wanted to say. Now there's an addition to my answer that explains how you can do what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you very much you are magican :) where to add some karma here :) ? May I have some other questions now I am using `\usepackage[dvips,dvipdfm,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=red,linkcolor=red,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}` but this also colrs author name and reference, is there a way to color only reference ? And it would be great if this reference would be clicable, like if you click on author name or number it takes you to reference section in document, can LatTeX do this ?

Comment: I see that `\DeclareRobustCommand` is some kind of macro. Can you please explain what is ~ and #1 stands for. My assumption are that #1 is "first argument" and ~ is space. I've tried little bit modify your code to `\DeclareRobustCommand{\citeext}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}~\citeyearpar{#1}~\cite{#1}}` but this gives me year in square bracket, would it be possible to have it in round brackets ? Also why I am unable to use `\citep` or `\cited` for properly displaying author name, but `\citeauthor` works as expected, is it another type of "function" or what ?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `\usepackage[sort&compress,square,comma,numbers]{natbib}` command with round `\usepackage[sort&compress,round,comma,numbers]{natbib}`.

Find more options here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/More_Bibliographies

Comment: Mhhh, do you think that will really help? This just gives '(1)' instead of '[1]' for numeric citations. The OP seems to want an Author-Year style.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  Have a look to [How do I write a good answer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)