# ACM in-text citation style

Tags: citing, acmart

According to the [ACM guidelines on citation style](https://www.acm.org/publications/authors/reference-formatting):

> When a citation is part of a sentence, the name of the author is NOT enclosed in brackets, but the year is: "So we see that Burando et al. [1999]..."

However, `\citet{author2022}` creates `Author et al. [1]` instead of `Author et al. [2022`]. Am I misunderstanding or using `\citet` wrong?

Comment: Please see the example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82907/citet-and-citep-behaves-like-cite).